# Ways to deploy Node.js in a production environment?

Tags: server, software-installation, nodejs

What is the recommended way to deploy Node.js on Ubuntu 12.04 in a production environment?

I saw [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Echris-lea/+archive/node.js/), but I don't know if is well-maintained, working, or even trustworthy.

I know that it is easy install Node.js manually, but it seems to me that installing it using the Ubuntu packages manager will allow me to save some management time and will be more integrated with how the underlying server is being currently management.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu / Install NodeJS & npm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312536/ubuntu-install-nodejs-npm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after read lot of posts and pages that talk about Node.js deployment-installation, I must said that Chris PPA is mentioned in tons of them as an official source. Beside one can see her PPA linked at the [Github Node.js wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager).

So, seem to me that is trust enough to be used in production, what made it the choice if you want keep your system updated using standards Ubuntu tools.