# Ubuntu / Install NodeJS & npm

Tags: nodejs, javascript, npm

I'm trying to install nodejs and npm, however, it fails. This is my terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nodejs : Conflicts: npm
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What to do? I'm kinda lost :(

Comment: Which Ubuntu version? I'm on 13.04 and it works fine.

Comment: 12.04 LTS is the version.

Comment: Oli's answer worked for me.
Rather, what he said was true for me, which was, that I already had npm (from installing nodejs from the repos) and did not need to install npm separately. I am writing this as an answer because I can neither upvote his answer (which requires 15 reputation) nor can I comment on his answer (it requires 50!).

Answer (score 14):

## Just execute this commands!

Installing Node.js via [package-manager](/questions/tagged/package-manager):

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

### Check version:

```
$ npm -v
1.4.9
$ node -v
v0.10.28
```

For more info visit this **[guide](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint-elementary-os)**.

Comment: chris-lea is no longer the ideal ppa. https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you have one of the nodejs PPAs installed. One I use has `npm` distributed as part of the `nodejs` package and it's impossible and unneccessary to install both.

Install `nodejs` and see if you can run `npm`.

Comment: I get a lot of unmet dependencies. I can install all of them except nodejs-dev which fails due to  nodejs-dev : Depends: nodejs (= 0.8.22-1chl1~precise1) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Yes, I've added ppa:chris-lea/node.js as nodejs.org tells.

Comment: Any ideas on what to do? :(

Comment: `nodejs-dev` looks like it has fallen behind. Talk to Chris Lea and ask if he can update the PPA accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the [Node.js guide](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```