# Installing npm /nodejson ubuntu

Tags: apt, nodejs

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

then I get this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

     npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-ansi but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
```

even tough nodejs exists on the system, should I install separately each dependency how can I install them in one bunch?

also I've tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-dev
```

and I get this:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs-dev : Depends: nodejs (= 0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

why it say's that nodejs doesn't exist, if it is on the system already installed?, if its broken how could I fix it? I've tried to remove it and install again, but didn't helped, any ideas?

**EDIT**

```
npm:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.3.10~dfsg-1
  Version table:
     1.3.10~dfsg-1 0
        500 http://kg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
nodejs:
  Installed: 4.2.1-2nodesource1~trusty1
  Candidate: 4.2.1-2nodesource1~trusty1
  Version table:
 *** 4.2.1-2nodesource1~trusty1 0
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://kg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
node-abbrev:
  Installed: 1.0.4-2
  Candidate: 1.0.4-2
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.4-2 0
        500 http://kg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
node-ansi:
  Installed: 0.2.1-1
  Candidate: 0.2.1-1
  Version table:
 *** 0.2.1-1 0
        500 http://kg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
node-archy:
  Installed: 0.0.2-1
  Candidate: 0.0.2-1
  Version table:
 *** 0.0.2-1 0
        500 http://kg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version ?

Comment: Also, here maybe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/312536/ubuntu-install-nodejs-npm?rq=1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30527/discussion-between-a-b-and-user3112115).

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nodejs`

Comment: Again the output of `apt-cache policy npm nodejs node-abbrev node-ansi node-archy`

Comment: And please delete the old comments

Comment: Not your edits in your question. The comments below your question. Please add the output of the command above again.

Comment: @A.B.  added the out of the command

Comment: And `sudo apt-get install npm` give you the exact same message ?

Comment: @hg8 the first code in my post, that is what it output, dependencies...how to solve this?

Comment: Start `sudo apt-get install npm` again and give us the output

Answer (score 1):

First we try to force the installation of the necessary packages

```
sudo apt-get install node-abbrev node-ansi node-archy 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nodejs
```

And after `apt-cache policy npm nodejs node-abbrev node-ansi node-archy` you have this

```
npm:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.3.10~dfsg-1
  Version table:
     1.3.10~dfsg-1 0
        500 http://kg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
nodejs:
  Installed: 4.2.1-2nodesource1~trusty1
  Candidate: 4.2.1-2nodesource1~trusty1
  Version table:
 *** 4.2.1-2nodesource1~trusty1 0
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://kg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
node-abbrev:
  Installed: 1.0.4-2
  Candidate: 1.0.4-2
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.4-2 0
        500 http://kg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
node-ansi:
  Installed: 0.2.1-1
  Candidate: 0.2.1-1
  Version table:
 *** 0.2.1-1 0
        500 http://kg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
node-archy:
  Installed: 0.0.2-1
  Candidate: 0.0.2-1
  Version table:
 *** 0.0.2-1 0
        500 http://kg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

And since I get no further feedback from you

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs=0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Comment: This did it for me. Thank you.